# files bypassing filetype selection in php

Tags: php, forms, file-type

i've got if/else in place to make sure only certain types of audio can be uploaded, but it doesn't seem to be working as other file types(images) are making it past my upload form. What's wrong with my code?

```
<?php 

 if($_POST['submit']=="in_mp3") 

{ 
$_FILES['file']['name'] = str_replace (" ", "", $_FILES['file']['name']);
if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") { 
        if (($_FILES['file']['type'] == "audio/mpeg" or "audio/ogg") || ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/force-download")) { 
            if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 6097152) {             
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "sound/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
                       echo "File has been stored in your uploads directory.";} 
else { echo "Please upload a file that is under 5 mb!";} 
} else { 
    echo "Please upload a mp3 or ogg file!"; 
    exit;} 
} else { echo "Please enter a file.";} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your `if` condition. The problem is that you evaluate "audio/ogg", which is not equal to "", and therefore, your `if` condition is always met. Try:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "audio/mpeg" || $_FILES['file']['type'] == "audio/ogg" || $_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/force-download") {
```

You could also check the file extension:

```
if (in_array(end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'])), array('mpg','mpeg', 'm2v', 'mp2', 'mp3', 'ogv', 'oga', 'ogx', 'ogg', 'spx')))
```

Comment: Also, the 'type' provided by browsers will most often be incorrect; don't rely on it.

Comment: @Evert This is true. As the code is now, however, no unaccepted file type will be uploaded.

Comment: ah so 
  ||
means or in php?
is there something more reliable than type I should use? What could cause it to be incorrect?

Comment: @John You could use both, `||` has a greater precedence than `OR`. I felt it was unnecessary to have both `||` and `OR`, as in your question, but this changed nothing. The problem was that you evaluated `"audio/ogg"`, which is not equal to `""`, and therefore, your `if` condition was always met. I added `$_FILES['file']['type'] == ` to your `if` condition.

Comment: @John You could also check filename extension. Provided example in my edited answer.